# Android Popup box similar to google license?

Tags: android

Hmm, looking at the way android popup it's text for the license with scroll, anyway to replicate it? Screen as below[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating this pop up you need to do like this.

```
1) create an activity as like your displaying popup

2) add below section to the manifest file 

   <activity android:name=".popupActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">//====> this makes the activity to display like pop up when call make to this activity
```

when you call this activity through intent its look like what you require..

Answer (score 0):

**Please use custom Dialogue box and add some scrollview and linear layout into it. Then put your actual text into it.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this android [popup library](https://github.com/00ec454/pop) with your custom layout. Very simple to use with one line of code in your activity.

```
Pop.on(this).with()
                .title(R.string.title) //you can skip if you don't need title
                .layout(R.layout.license).show();
```